# Reverse DNS PTR lookups ocurring on each connection

Tags: networking, dns

I'm running a Debian-based VPS (Linux vps 2.6.32-042stab092.3 #1 SMP Sun Jul 20 13:27:24 MSK 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux) which is behaving a bit strange. Whenever a new connection is established to it, it performs a PTR lookup.

I'm running some performance tests on it on port 80, where a Python script on a remote machine continuously fetches a page on the VPS. For every page request a new PTR lookup is being made, which ends up in thousands of active DNS requests.

I was monitoring this with `tcpdump -n port not 22 and host not MY_REMOTE_IP`. So `-n` is to prevent lookups.

I'm also monitoring with `ntop`, where -n is also used.

If I stop `ntop` and look at `tcpdump`, I get the lookups. If I stop `tcpdump` and start `ntop`, I also get them. So it might be fair to assume that none of them is causing the lookup.

There's also `xinetd` running in the background, which apparently also uses PTR lookups. But if I stop that service, the lookups still occur.

Then there's `/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5`, which, when getting killed, also doesn't change the situation.

Same goes for `rabbitmq-server` and erlangs `epmd`. `authbind` also doesn't seem to be responsible, and `screen` as well and stopping `openvpn`, which is usually running as a server, also makes no difference.

Wuaht on earth could be causing this?

Here's the process tree.

```
init
`- SCREEN -AmdS py-http authbind python server.py ---scr:py-http
|  `- python server.py ---scr:py-http
`- /sbin/getty 38400 tty2
`- /sbin/getty 38400 console
`- /bin/sh /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server
|  `- /usr/lib/erlang/erts-5.9.1/bin/beam.smp -W w -K true -A30 -P 1048576 -- -root /usr/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /var/lib/rabbitmq -- -pa /us
t start_sasl -config /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq -kernel inet_default_connect_o
|     `- inet_gethost 4
|     |  `- inet_gethost 4
`- /usr/lib/erlang/erts-5.9.1/bin/epmd -daemon
`- /usr/sbin/ntop -d -L -u ntop -P /var/lib/ntop --access-log-file /var/log/ntop/access.log -i venet0:0 -p /etc/ntop/protocol.list -O /var/log/ntop
`- /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
`- /usr/sbin/cron
`- /usr/sbin/xinetd -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid -stayalive -inetd_compat -inetd_ipv6
`- /usr/sbin/sshd
|  `- sshd: user [priv]
|     `- sshd: user@pts/0
|        `- -bash
|           `- htop
`- sendmail: MTA: accepting connections
`- /usr/sbin/openvpn --writepid /var/run/openvpn.server.pid --daemon ovpn-server --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf
`- /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/run/saslauthd -n 2
|  `- /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/run/saslauthd -n 2
`- /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
`- upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
`- /sbin/udevd --daemon
|  `- /sbin/udevd --daemon
|  `- /sbin/udevd --daemon
`- upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
```

**Update**

This lookup occurs on every new connection, be it on port 80, or 22, any port, it doesn't matter which one.

Result from **Strace** for one HTTP request

```
sendto(10, "C~\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0016\00270\003168\003192\7in-add"..., 43, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 43
print statement in server.py -> request #5 from client 192.168.70.6
sendto(10, "\23\372\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0016\00270\003168\003192\7in-add"..., 43, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 43
sendto(9, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Fri, 24 O"..., 146, 0, NULL, 0) = 146
```

**Sysdig** cannot be used, as it's not possible to install it on the VPS

**iptables** logging results in the following entries:
For new ssh connections:

```
Oct 24 06:06:11 vps kernel: [6547020.638594] DNS Traffic match:IN= OUT=venet0 SRC=VPS_IP_ADDRESS DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=99 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=56490 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=50366 DPT=53 LEN=79 UID=0 GID=0
```

For new http connections:

```
Oct 24 06:06:53 vps kernel: [6547062.417763] DNS Traffic match:IN= OUT=venet0 SRC=VPS_IP_ADDRESS DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=71 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=32702 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=59091 DPT=53 LEN=51 UID=1000 GID=1000
```

**ss** results in

```
ESTAB      0      0            VPS_IP_ADDRESS:42414         8888:53     users:(("python",2375,10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'll note that the invocation of ntop in the process tree you shared, doesn't seem to have the `-n` flag:

```
/usr/sbin/ntop -d -L -u ntop -P /var/lib/ntop --access-log-file /var/log/ntop/access.log -i venet0:0 -p /etc/ntop/protocol.list -O /var/log/ntop
```

but I assume given your statements about the queries continuing even with ntop killed, that it is not the issue.  Further, to clarify, I am assuming that the machine doing the the lookups is the same machine handling the requests on port 80.

Given that, the following are some debugging ideas:

## ss

If the program in question is keeping the socket around for a while, you can likely use `ss` (or netstat) with the `-p` flag to find the owner of the source port that you should be seeing in your tcpdumps.

## Strace

The first suspect should be the application handling the requests.  I'm assuming that the following python process running under screen is the application you are testing?

```
 `- SCREEN -AmdS py-http authbind python server.py ---scr:py-http
|  `- python server.py ---scr:py-http
```

You might consider running this process under strace and see if it is generating the DNS traffic.  For instance something like:

```
strace -e trace=sendmsg,sendto -f YOUR_PROGRAM_HERE
```

and then carefully looking at the output for messages that look like they were sent to port 53:

```
[pid  3367] sendmsg(20, {msg_name(16)={sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.254")}, msg_iov(1)=[{"\31\322\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0014\0014\0018\0018\7in-addr\4arp"..., 38}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 38
```

## ss in a loop

If the program in question is quickly closing its socket, it may be hard to get information about it from ss or netstat.

However, one possibility us is to write a script that polls the `ss` command repeatedly. You would be betting on getting lucky enough to catch one of the lookups:

```
while true; do ss -p -n -u | tail -n +2; done
```

You can add a filter to the ss command to narrow it down if you see lots of other UDP traffic on that machine.  Whether this works or not depends on you getting lucky.

## Sysdig

You could use the relatively new [`sysdig`](http://www.sysdig.org/) utility to look at all sendmsg or sendto system calls:

```
sudo sysdig evt.type=sendmsg or evt.type=sendto | grep ':53'
```

And the output will have the process name (in this case nslookup):

```
47852 01:15:33.454946732 4 nslookup (3349) > sendmsg fd=20(<4>) size=38 tuple=0.0.0.0:49847->192.168.1.254:53
```

## iptables

iptables allows you to log the userid of the process that generated the packet.  If most of your services are running as the same user, this won't be too helpful, but it could be if you have service-specific users.  A set of iptable rules as follows:

```
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -j LOG --log-prefix="DNS Traffic match:" --log-uid
```

would log all outbound dns traffic with the associated UID.  Depending on your logging setup, you could find this via kmesg or whever your syslog messages go and the output would look something like:

```
Oct 24 01:09:53 localhost.localdomain kernel: DNS Traffic match:IN= OUT=enp0s3 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=192.168.1.254 LEN=66 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35264 PROTO=UDP SPT=51767 DPT=53 LEN=46 UID=1000 GID=1000
```

From this output I can see that the process in question had UID of 1000, which at least narrows my search.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the results to the question. In short: haven't been able to get to the ground of this issue.

Comment: Actually, it looks to me like you /have/ found the issue.  When you connect over 22, SSH is likely doing the dns lookup, you can stop it by adding `UseDns no` to your sshd config and restarting the daemon.  On 80, it looks like your python process is clearly doing the lookup.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I forgot to mention that I had tried `UseDNS no`, but after seeing that it had no effect, judging from the lookups caused by Python, and not looking specifically for the ones caused by SSH, I thougt this had no effect, and commented it out. I now also noticed that RabbitMQ's Management console, HTTP based, doesn't cause the lookups. For SSH I'll be leaving it on, but now I know that I need to focus on Python. Apparently other ports than 22 and 80 were not affected. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Found it. in **Twisted**, `request.getClient()` causes such a lookup. That's why I had two lookups in the **Strace**: one for the print statement, and one from the return value. In both cases the string would get formed by using that function.