# Why does my Linux do a reverse DNS lookup (PTR in-addr.arpa) on establishing a network connection (including simply on boot) and how do I turn it off?

Tags: networking, dns

This is a personal machine, no servers or anything. Xubuntu (a lighter Ubuntu). Establishing a network connection means Network Manager shows connected. It does not refer to every connection through the network as was the case [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163871/reverse-dns-ptr-lookups-ocurring-on-each-connection), nor does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163871/reverse-dns-ptr-lookups-ocurring-on-each-connection#comment268896_163903) or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163871/reverse-dns-ptr-lookups-ocurring-on-each-connection#comment268897_163903) apply. I believe this happens on a clean minimal install too. The address being looked up is the private 10.0.. address of the system.

Comment: Can you share the address being looked up? Is it the host address?

Comment: Good point. Added.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the correct address to `/etc/hosts` then the resolution (the system trying to find out its own name) will be local:

In `/etc/hosts` add a line like this (10.0.x.y is a placeholder for your actual address):

```
10.0.x.y the.name.of.your.host
```

That's quick and dirty, you might want to investigate more on how your DNS is configured and which service is trying to find out its FQDN or just the name.